# Использование return в С/С++

Tags: c++, c, return

Как понять что надо ставить в выражении return? Когда ставить return 0 и все return c другими выражениями? как определить что надо возвращать ? я имею ввиду как определить что ставить после return(? )?
  я просто не понимаю, что надо возвращать, я не понимаю что писать после return  в скобках   return(?)?
вот например :

```
int find_substr(char *s1, char *s2)
{
  register int t;
  char *p, *p2;

  for(t=0; s1[t]; t++) {
    p = &s1[t];
    p2 = s2;

    while(*p2 && *p2==*p) {
      p++;
      p2++;
    }
    if(!*p2) return t; /* 1-й оператор return */
  }
   return -1; /* 2-й оператор return */
}
```

почему там return -1, что это -1 обозначает , почему там стоит именно -1, а не 0 или не  p?
как вообще понять в каких обстоятельствах и что ставить после return?

Comment: 1) В return нужно ставить то, что должна вернуть функция. А что она должна вернуть, в каких ситуациях, и что означают возвращаемые значения - решает её автор, и описывает это в документции. В дапнном случае, очевидно, -1 означает что подстрока не найдена, >=0 - позиция найденной подстроки.

2) Прежде чем задавать подобные вопросы хорошо бы всё-таки хоть немного полистать учебник для начинающих. Зачитывать его вслух вам тут никто не будет.

Answer (score 8):

Ваш вопрос по сути не имеет смысла. Он слишком общий что ли, сродни вопросу "когда нужно употреблять букву **А**". Ответ на вопрос "что надо ставить в выражении return"  в каждом конкретном случае зависит от логики  функции, поэтому не существует какого-то универсального рецепта, который бы говорил, что "вот здесь пиши **return 0**, а тут **return "Hello world"**. 
Что касается приведенного примера - постарайтесь понять, что (а главное как) делает эта функция, тогда, вероятно, вы увидите логику в том, почему эта функция возвращает те или иные значения. В частности, -1 в функциях поиска обычно подразумевает, что искомое значение не было найдено. Однако, еще раз повторю - это лишь конкретный пример одной функции. Ответ на ваш вопрос должен вытекать из логики реализуемой функции в каждом конкретном случае

Answer (score 5):

Данная функция, судя по всему, ищет подстроку в строке.

В случае успеха она возвращает `t` - позицию найденной подстроки (порядковый номер первого символа подстроки в данной строке).

В случае провала возвращает `-1`, т.к. это не является валидным порядковым номером символа в строке (нет символа с номером `-1`) и тот, кто вызвал эту функцию поймет, что подстрока не найдена.

Вообще возврат `-1` - довольно распространенная практика в функциях, возвращающих позицию какого-либо объекта в упорядоченном списке.

Answer (score 1):

```
int find_substr(char *s1, char *s2)
```

в описании функции первым идет тип переменной что она должна вернуть после выполнения.

Тебе решать нужно что-то от функции получить или нет.

Скажем,

```
int iResult=find_substr("строка 1","стр");
if (iResult==-1) //поиск окончился неудачей
...
;
else //поиск успешен!
...
;
```

В операнд return добавляешь нужные тебе значения (0,-1,-2, что угодно типа int), а потом анализируешь результат в iResult.

Если не нужно чего-то ждать от функции, то вместо int указываешь тип void.